# Child divs overwrite width of parent div

Tags: html, css

I keep on digging the answer to my problem and keep trying everything but all attempts I have made so far fail. Here it goes:

My parent panel has the `id` as `secondPanel` and the width of this is fixed by a JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("secondPanel").style.width = (screen.width-12) + "px";
```

I didn't use "width:100%" because it produces a scroll bar at the bottom of my view port. and I want the position of my layout to stay the same even if the browser size changes.

```
#secondPanel{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding:0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:2px;
    border-color: black;
    background: red;
}

#tryP{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:2px;
    border-color: black;
    background: white;
}

#childDiv{
    float:left;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:2px;
    border-color: black;
}
```

but, every time I put a child `div` **inside** the parent `div` and place a `width` for it, the scroll bar appears again **even** if the `width` of it is **less** than the `width` of the parent. But when I put a `p`, the scroll bar doesn't show up. What can I do about this? What is the problem with my child `div`?

Comment: Try giving each one `position:relative`  and you should be able to use `width:100%;` then too

Comment: Can you share fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Set childDiv width to 100%

```css
#childDiv{
width:100%;
float:left;
border-style: solid;
border-width:2px;
border-color: black;
}
```

Comment: everytime i use "width:100%" the scroll bar appears